# Existence of non-trivial bounded linear functionals with a quasi-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Is it well known, and easy to prove, that if we define the norm of $L^p$ with $p<1$ in the usual way, $ \| \cdot \|_{L^p} $ is not actually a norm because it does not satisfy subadditivity. At the same time, if there is a linear functional $l$ that satisfies $$|l(f)| \le M \|f\|_{L^p} $$ for all $f \in L^p$ and some $M > 0$, then $l=0$.

I wonder whether it is generally true that with a quasi-norm $\mathcal{N}$, which violates subadditivity, the only bounded linear functionals is trivial (if we pretend $\mathcal{N}$ is a norm).

In particular, I have the following example in mind (from Exercise 15 in Chapter 2 of Stein and Shakarchi's *Functional Analysis*).

> Consider the weak-type space, consisting of all functions $f$ for which $m(\{ x : |f(x)| > \alpha \}) \leq \frac{A}{\alpha}$ for some $A$ and all $\alpha > 0$. One might hope to deﬁne a norm on this space by taking the “norm” of $f$ to be the least $A$ for which the above inequality holds. Denote this quantity by $\mathcal{N}(f)$.

We can show that $\mathcal{N}(f)$ is not a genuine norm because it does not satisfy subadditivity through the following example.

> The function $f(x) = 1/ | x |$ has $\mathcal{N}(f) = 2$. But if $f_N = \frac{1}{N} [f(x + 1) + f(x + 2) + \cdots + f(x + N)]$, then $\mathcal{N}(f_N) \ge c \log N$.

The textbook also claims that this space has no non-trivial bounded linear functionals.

Comment: L_p with $0<p<1$ is metrizable and the metric $d(f,g)=\|f-g\|^p_p$ I makes the space a complete metric spca. The bounded sets are similar to the case $p\geq1$

Comment: @Oliver Díaz, I knew. That's why I wrote "if ..." The point is not that we can find a well-behaved norm, but rather that if we treat a non-norm as if it were a norm, we would have trouble finding non-trivial bounded linear functionals.

Comment: That is why I also added a description of the bounded sets which is all you need to determine whether an operator is bounded or not…

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4556006/121671) may be of interest to you

Comment: For functional s on L_p with $0<p<1$ this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4413489/121671) may also be of interest

Comment: Thank you @OliverDíaz. I've corrected a few minor errors in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4556006/121671). (Submitted. Not sure if they are visible to you.)

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the edit. Do the postings I referred to you answer you question? Or there is something else I am missing.

Comment: @OliverDíaz In the weak-type example that I have posted, the relevant quasi-norm is $L^{\infty,1}$. I don't see how to use either the information in your postings, or $d(f,g) = \|f-g\|_p^p$ for $L^p$, to prove the non-existence of a non-trivial bounded linear functional with $L^{\infty,1}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140599/discussion-between-petra-axolotl-and-oliver-diaz).

Comment: Are you still interested in this problem?

Comment: Yes. I tried to prove that $L^{\infty,0}$ is not locally convex without success. So I decided to take a break and come back to the problem later. Ideally I would want a proof as simple as Proposition 1 in [your post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4418268/291842).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the OP is no, it is not true in general. The key issue is local convexity.

In the context of the OP's posting, a ***quasi-metric*** space $X$ is a non empty set $X$ along with a function $\rho:X\times X\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ such that

1. $\rho(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$,
2. $\rho(x,y)=\rho(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in X$,
3. there is $K\geq1$ with $\rho(x,y)\leq K(\rho(x,z)+\rho(z,y))$ for all $x,y,z\in X$.
   When $X$ is a vector space with a quasi-metric $\rho$ that is translation invariant ($\rho(x_z,y+z)=\rho(x,y)$ for all $x,y,x\in X$), and homogenous ($\rho(cx,cy)=|c|\rho(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$ and $c\in\mathbb{F}$) quasi metric, then $\rho$ is a quasi-norm and $(X,\rho)$ a ***quasi-normed space***.

The quasi-metric $\rho$ induces a topology $\tau(\rho)$ on $X$ which can be construct by uniformities: The sets $U_r=\{(x,y): \rho(x,y)<r\}$ form a basis for a uniformity; in fact the collection $U_{1/n}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, is a countable basis for the uniformity, and so $(X,\tau(\rho))$ is metrizable (see, Kelly, J. *General Topology*, Springer-Verlag, chapter 6).

A more direct result by Macías-Segovia and  later by Aimar, Jaffei and Nitti (see Paluszynski, M and Stempak, P., *On quasi-metric and metric spaces*, Proceedings of the AMS, Vol 137, 12, 2009, pp. 4307-4312)  states that

> Proposition: If $(X,\rho)$ is a quasi-metric (resp. quais-normed) space, then
> there is $0<p\leq1$ ($p=\tfrac{\log(2)}{\log(2K)}$) and a metric (resp. norm) $d_p$ on $X$ such that
> $\tilde{\rho}:=d^{1/p}$ is a quai-metric (resp. quasi-norm) on $X$ equivalent to $\rho$ (i.e., $c\rho\leq\tilde{\rho}\leq d\rho$ for constants $c,d>0$);
> furthermore,
> $$\tilde{\rho}(x,y)\leq \Big(\tilde{\rho}^p(x,z)+\tilde{\rho}^p(z,y)\Big)^{1/p},\qquad x,y,z\in X$$

It is clear that the topology induced by the quasi-metric $\rho$ and the metric $d_p$  are the same.

If $X$ is a quasi-normed vector space, ans  $d_p$ is complete, the $(X,d_p)$ is an $F$-space. Examples of this situation are already mentioned by the OP: $L_p(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ for $0<p<1$ with $\rho(x)=\|x\|_p$ and $L^{\infty,p}(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}),m)$ ($m$ Lebeusge measure on the line with $\rho(x)=\sup_{t>0}\{t m^{1/p}(|x|>t))$ with $0<p\leq 1$. These spaces are not normable (there is no norm equivalent to $d_p$) since  $L_p$ ($0<p<1$ ) is not (in general) locally convex, and neither is $L^{\infty,1}(\mathbb{R})$. Hence their dual spaces are trivial.

This is in contrast to $L_p(\mu)$ with $p\geq1$ or $L^{\infty,p}(\mu)$ with $p>1$. The former is already a complete normed space; the later has a norm $\newcommand\vertiii[1]{{\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert #1 
    \right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert}}
\vertiii{\;}_p$ that is equivalent to the quasi-norm $[\;]_p$ (see [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4556266/121671) for example).

Comment: I completely get it that if a quasi-norm is not locally convex, the dual space must be trivial. What I think is still missing is that $L^{\infty,1}(R)$ is not locally convex. (I have not studied topology. In fact, local convexity is so far not even mentioned in the textbook I am using. So an elementary proof would be much appreciated!)

Comment: The example $f_N$ shows that $L^{\inty,1}$ is not, for $f_N$ is a convex combination of functions in the *ball*  $B(0;2)$.

Comment: I understand. My question is whether the existence of such $f_N$ necessarily means that *every* other function $f$ is also a convex combination of functions in a neighbourhood the origin. In the other proof of yours about $L^p, p<1$, it was explicitly shown to be valid for all $f$.

Comment: @PetraAxolotl: To show that the space is not locally convex is enough to consider one neighborhood of the form $B(0;r)$ and show that there are elements in that neighborhood say, $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ such that a (not every, but just some) convex combination $f:=\alpha_1 f_1+\ldots + \alpha_m f_m$ ($0<\alpha_j<1$, $\sum^m_{j=1}\alpha_j=1$) is not in $B(0;r)$.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are examples of such spaces which do have non trivial linear functionals.  For example the discrete version of $L^p$, i.e. $\ell^p$.  Point evaluations do the trick.  (If you want a silly example, take a finite dimensional space and put a suitable quai-norm on it).